# rxjs Observable.catch() not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm running into an exception that's killing my application, and I can't seem to catch() / consume it. I'm very new to this so I'm probably doing something wrong with the `catch`?

```
private callConfigService(): Observable<Map<string,string>> {

    try {
        let confObs = this.contentService.fetchContentUsingGET(id, store, locale, null, false)
            .catch((res) => {
                console.log('Retrieving config FAILED! ', res);    // not hit
                return Observable.from([new Map<string,string>()]);
            }
        ).subscribe(
            (res) => { console.log('fetchContentUsingGET : ', res); },  // not worried about success scenario
            (err) => { console.log('error response: ', err); }  // not hit
         );  
    } catch (exception) {
        console.log('???', exception);  // not hit
    } finally {
        console.log('?????');   // hit
    }
    return Observable.of(new Map<string,string>()); // not hit
}
```

Unfortunately the `fetchConfigUsingGET` call is from a library, so I'm not sure what's inside. But it looks like a hot observable because it yields a 404 exception without me even calling `subscribe()`

What I don't get is why the `catch()` is completely skipped?

```
Uncaught * e {_body: "{"status":404,"error":"StatusCodeError","data":"404 - undefined"}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: t…}          bundle.umd.js:5
```

Comment: Do you actually *use* `confObs` anywhere? What's the error message you're seeing?

Comment: Nope, I don't use it at all, the above declaration is it. This is all part of a framework, so tough to get a standalone example, but error is: `EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 null for URL: `

Comment: ``catch`` is called when an exception is thrown. As you said, you cannot tell if the behaviour of ``fetchConfigUsingGET`` is the same as the http get call that would throw an exception for a 4xx http status code. Just subscribe to the ``confObs`` and take a look at what you get.

Comment: do a call that fails and print confObs to figure out how to work with it.  let confObs = this.configService.fetchConfigUsingGET(id, store, locale, null, false); console.log(confObs);

Comment: Updated the code. It's not hitting any of what I'd expect it to, even with subscribe() etc. I now see this in the console: `Uncaught 
* e {_body: "{"status":404,"error":"StatusCodeError","data":"404 - undefined"}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: t…}` Just not sure how to `catch()` that?

Comment: If you can, please create [a self-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this? Add OnError handler in subscrible operator.

```
let confObs = this.contentService.fetchContentUsingGET(id, store, locale, null, false)
                  .catch((res) => {
                      console.log('Retrieving config FAILED! ', res);
                      return Observable.from([new Map<string,string>()]);
                  })
                  .subscribe(
                      (res) => { console.log('fetchContentUsingGET : ', res);},
                      (err) => { console.log('fetchContentUsingGET.Error : ', err);},
                      () => { //on completed }
                  );
```

Comment: good call. I'd ended up adding this locally, though it didn't help unfortunately. I'll update the code above with it.

Comment: If that is the case, exception should happen in fetchContentUsingGET without necessary handler. You have to check the library.

Comment: If `fetchContentUsingGET()` throws the exception, then my `catch()` wouldn't be able to catch it? (Sorry, new to rxjs...)

Comment: No, not really. The unhandled exception must happen before returning Observable object.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks, I'll see if I can find out about the `fetchContentUsingGET()` workings.